# Data binding to a GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, datagridview

Basically, I'm binding data to GridView from SQL source on PageLoad event. When I refer to data during RowCreated event, I get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error.

`.aspx` code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20" Style="table-layout:fixed" AutoGenerateColumns="true" CellSpacing="4" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="File_Name" GridLines="None" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" ForeColor="#333333" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated">
                    <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" PageButtonCount="10" Position="Bottom" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnFileName" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("File_Name") %>' CommandName="Download" Text='<%# Eval("File_Name") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

`.cs` code for `PageLoad` event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MEHDI-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=PIMS; Integrated Security=true;");
        {                
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    String sql = "select * from dbo.Documents";
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandText = sql;
                    con.Open();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        adp.Fill(ds);
                    }
                    DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
                    myTable = ds.Tables[0];
                    this.GridView1.DataSource = myTable;
                    this.GridView1.DataBind();
                }
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    con.Close();
                }  
        }                
            MultiView1.SetActiveView(vHome);
            btnBacktoHome.Visible = false;
            lblStatus.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

`.cs` code for `RowCreated` Event:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable myGridTable = null;
        TableCell tblCell1;
        myGridTable = (DataTable)((GridView)sender).DataSource;
        if (myGridTable != null)
        {
            tblCell1 = e.Row.Cells[myGridTable.Columns["File"].Ordinal];
            tblCell1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        } 
    }
```

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error is being thrown on `tblCell1 = e.Row.Cells[myGridTable.Columns["File"].Ordinal];` line in `RowCreated` event. So basically, when I refer to GridView1 datasource (`this.GridView1.DataSource = myTable;`) in `RowCreated` event through (`tblCell1 = e.Row.Cells[myGridTable.Columns["File"].Ordinal];`), it is telling me that there is no data bounded in `this.GridView1.DataSource = myTable;`. How can it be true when I'm binding data from SQL source on PageLoad(). Can anyone see the problem?

Comment: It doesnt have to mean that there is no data bound to the gridview. Could also be it can't find a column called "File". Check if `myGridTable` is null.

Comment: @FlorianGl myGridTable isn't null. It has GridView1 data binded with it.

Comment: @FlorianGl I changed the column name `"File"` to another column name `"File_Name"` and now error message is `Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.`

Comment: How many cells does the enumerable `e.Row.Cells` have? What is the value of `myGridTable.Columns["File_Name"].Ordinal`?

Comment: Where do you close your connection?

Comment: @FlorianGl `e.Row.Cells` Count is 1 while value for `myGridTable.Columns["File_Name"].Ordinal` is 23.

Comment: @MartinSmellworse Code has been edited.

Comment: @FlorianGl I think we have reached to same point where I started off. As you notice number of `e.Row.Cells` is 1. I think it is first column of the GridView (First Column Name= "`DocumentsID`"). Cause if I run the above code with line, `tblCell1 = e.Row.Cells[myGridTable.Columns["DocumentsID"].Ordinal];`, code runs without an error (although with no desired results). Why `e.Row.Cells` not reading beyond index(0). Maybe because it has no more columns beyond index `'0'`? Also if it is not e.Row.Cells reading data from sql, then how is data popped into `myGridTable`.

Comment: @FlorianGl are you there? If you notice in GridView definition code in .aspx, I've a template field in the GridView. Do you think it might be causing the problem?

Comment: @LattarSingh e.Row.Cells does not read your data from sql. It just holds the information about the created row. This occurs after new data is added the the `GridView.DataSource` object. I don't think it got anything to do with your templated column. Does your `GridView` display the data correctly?

Comment: @FlorianGl If I take out RowCreated() event, ofcourse my `GridView` displays the data correctly. If you notice, I've `EditRecord`,`DeleteRecord` etc., events and they all run perfectly. I think RowCreated() occurs before Data is bound with the rows. What I am failed to underdstand is, how come `myGridTable` has the desired data in it and why cant that data be inserted into e.Row.Cells when we are assigning it to it.

Comment: @LattarSingh Maybe, after it gets the data, it just looks how many entries there are and then creates blank rows and fires the events. After creating those rows, it creates the columns and fills the data. That would be my guess. Try using another event, maybe the RowDataBound-Event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx You can also use the same handler ;)